How to do partial indexing in pandas?
I am learning pandas and came across partial indexing in date time index. however, i am struggling to print a particular month's data using partial indexing.
These are the above code tried to print the data for the may month in 2023

df.loc['2023-05']

Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data (code, error, data). Never post them as screenshot, copy paste and format it instead.
